# Prevent Guzzle from returning text/html response with lumen response

Tags: php, lumen, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle with lumen to send sms via an API, the sending sms code is in a service used by a controller, after sending sms successfully I want to return json response. Example: `{"status":"success"}`

but instead I got text/html; charset=UTF-8 as below

`[CONNECT] [MIME_TYPE_IS] message: "application/json" [FILE_SIZE_IS] message: "Content-Length: 110" bytes_max: "110" [PROGRESS] bytes_max: "110"`

------------------------- sensSMS service code ----------------------------------

```
public function sendSms( $senderAddress, $receiverAddress, $message, $senderName){ 

$url = self::BASE_URL . '/smsmessaging/v1/outbound/' . urlencode($senderAddress) . '/requests';

      $args = array(
            'outboundSMSMessageRequest' => array(
                'address'                   => $receiverAddress,
                'senderAddress'             => $senderAddress,
                'senderName'                => urlencode($senderName),
                'outboundSMSTextMessage'    => array(
                    'message' => $message
                )
            )
        );

    $response = $this->client->post($url, [
        'json' => $args,
        'debug' => FALSE,
        'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getToken()
        ]
      ]);

    $contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to so, can you show the code snippet you are using to send sms via guzzle, specifically the part of your response from guzzle

Comment: okey below the code of sendSMS serivce

Comment: can you check what is the value of response header for content-type, is it `content-type: text/html`, after you get the response you can use `$response->getHeader('Content-Type')[0];` to get it

Comment: @MohamedSallamiRehouma did you figure out the issue here? I'm facing the same behaviour when returning `$response->getBody()` expecting the `application/json` response header but getting `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.  `$response->getHeader('Content-Type')[0]` returns `application\json`... Can't figure out why and where this is changed during the requests.

Comment: So I worked around it by doing a `return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);` instead of simply a `return $response->getBody()`. Not sure if this is appropriate but it does keep the expected `application/json` header.